# Is it normal for my boiler transformer to show intermittent drops in voltage?

Tags: boiler, nest

Since I installed a Nest-E I've seen my Weil-McLain boiler cut power to the R-wire and C-wire intermittently.

Voltage drops to nearly 0 and the Nest-E errors with E-195 no power. Other times thermostat works fine to control heat.

I'm trying to figure out if the transformer is bad or if the Nest is just not a good fit for this system.

How do I know if the transformer is going kaput?

Comment: What model is your boiler, or can you post a wiring diagram for it for that matter?

Comment: Weil McLain, EG-55-PIDN. All I have going from boiler to thermostat is a R, W, and C wire. No cooling in this 100 yr old house :)

Comment: Can you make sure the thing isn't cycling on a limit switch? (The LIMIT light should come on if all is well during a call for heat.  If the LIMIT light on the control turns off when the R wire gets power cut to it, then that's your problem)

Comment: Also, how is your boiler configured? (Hydronic vs hydronic + DHW coil vs steam?)

Comment: Thanks @ThreePhaseEel. It's steam. And it does have a limit switch. I will check that the next time power is cut.

Comment: Your boiler probably lacks an integrated control, which means that the limit switch is downstream of the thermostat most likely (check it anyway though).  Check the LWCO as well, too -- it *is* upstream of the thermostat in the "stock" steam configs on the Weil-McLain EG series.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel You called it. Saw it this morning --- LWCO triggered and power to the stat dropped. It all makes sense now -- time to fix some leaky radiators.

Comment: Write up what you find as an answer and I'll upvote it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The voltage drop I saw was due to the triggering of the low water cut off system. When the LWCO kicked on it dropped power to the thermostat. Thank you for the tip @ThreePhaseEel !

Gotta get some of those leaky radiators fixed.

As a side-note, the Ecobee handles the power drop better than the Nest. I tried two different Nest-E units and they both read 5-6 degree lower ambient temps while recovering from the power drop. The Ecobee stayed constant.

Answer (score 1):

If it is severing the R wire in response to a limit situation, that means the furnace's wiring is not compatible with the Nest.

The furnace is designed to have a simple mercury make-or-break 'stat. Interlocks are also make-or-break, so your furnace has simply placed them all in series **without caring about sequence**. As a result, some of those interlocks are interrupting the R line when they should be interrupting the W line.

Now, if your system also had air conditioning or auxiliary heat stages, they would also be shut off by an interlock that severs the R line.  Study the system carefully to see **if that is intentional/desired**.   If it is not, the furnace should be rewired so those R-line interlocks instead interrupt the W line, and nothing interrupts R.  That will make it compatible with the Nest.

If C is being interrupted, them you got C from the wrong place.

Comment: The C is being interrupted as well. Dang, sounds like it is not wired correctly then. I didn't install the C, but when the HVAC guy comes back I will bring this up. Much appreciated @Harper.

Answer (score 0):

The transformer typically will either work or will not.  I suspect that you have a loose connection somewhere that is making and breaking intermittently.

Comment: Ok, appreciate that insight. Will check along the wire path and the board.